# Access associated constant items without scope qualifier

Tags: rust

I would like to use the const `C` inside the impl `R6502` without having to specify the scope `R6502::`

```
use bit::BitIndex;

pub struct R6502 {
    pub sr: u8, // status register
}

impl R6502 {
    // status flag indexs
    const C: usize = 0;
    const Z: usize = 1;

    pub fn step(&mut self) {
        self.sr.set_bit(R6502::C, false); // this is what I have to do
        self.sr.set_bit(C, false); // this is what I want to do
    }
}
```

I tried use `self::C` and some other combinations of `use` to only get errors about items not found.

Comment: You say `self::C` doesn't work, but `Self::C` does.

Comment: I get unresolved import with that. I'm using 1.20

Comment: Works on the playground though: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=be07c2cf9daa912c6e988cb48c7ec58e&version=stable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use`ing of associated constants is not implemented in Rust 1.20. I haven't found an issue for that, so you can create your own issue in Rust GitHub repository.

In the meantime you can use type alias to reduce character count.

```
type P = R6502;
self.sr.set_bit(P::C, false);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I appreciate the workaround as well. I will look into creating an issue for this.